# Reference on Tutorial on CMFCToolbar customization?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, custom-controls, cmfctoolbar

I have looked through all possible MSDN articles, and have browsed a lot of web content in order to find tutorial on usage of the class CMFCToolbar.
There is very little information, and it almost is about basic features of the class.

I am looking for the following info:
**General question:**
How to implement a toolbar with custom images (bitmaps that are loaded from a file) that is based on the CMFCToolbar.
**Sub-questions:**
What methods I need to overload, what other classes I need to use
(do I need CMFCToolBarButton, CMFCToolBarImages).

Could you please give me references on tutorials, or provide information based on your experience.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Feature Pack controls (CMFCToolbar) are part of the [BCG](http://www.bcgsoft.com/) toolkit.  You oshould be able to find information and samples at their web site.

Comment: Thank you for the information, now I know about BCG, but still has no clue about CMFCToolbar/CBCGPTToolbar customization. Although BCG provides samples, but they are only binary files, which doesn't give me any useful information. If you know where to look for the examples of usage that are supported with source code could you let me know?

Comment: Admittedly, BCG (and Microsoft) do not supply good information on the Feature Pack.  Have you tried looking through the BCG support forums?

Comment: yes, I have, they lack needed information. I have found the following theme: http://www.bcgsoft.com/cgi-bin/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4924, which supports my opinion that MFC has very bad documentation, but still no useful information for me

Comment: I have managed to find working examples, it was simple, I just needed to download evaluation version of the MFC feature pack from BCG site. So thank you very much for the answer!